# loop values are not updated outside of the loop in C++

Tags: c++

I have a problem here. When I try to access `t1[val]` outside the loop, I get a garbage value.

```
int P[ ]={3,7,6,5,2,4,1,8};
int N[ ]={8,6,7,2,5,3,4,1}; 
int r= (sizeof(P)/sizeof(*P));
int s= (sizeof(N)/sizeof(*N));
int val=r/2 ;
int t1[val],t2[val],t3[val],t4[val],n=0,p=0;

for(int m=0;m< val;m++){
  t1[n]=P[m];
  t2[n]=N[m];
  n++;
}

cout << t1[val];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your loop, it is limited to **< val** which means in array values are written from **0** to **val-1** ,that is why when you are trying to print the value at **t1[val]** it is giving garbage value, I don't know what you want to do exactly but changing your loop in the below manner will solve your purpose

```
for(int m=0;m<=val;m++)
```

Even though the above code works for you it is wrong practice as it will write values beyond array boundary which is bad, and even C++ compiler will not raise any exception for this.

So it is suggested to use below statement to print last element of your array

```
cout<<t1[val-1]
```

Comment: _m=0;m<=val_ with this you are writing out of bounds

Comment: Yes, I understand that but as you know in C/C++ there is no boundary checking. I've written the answer to make him understand what mistake he was making, will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Array indices start from 0, so the higher valid index of `int t1[val]` is `val-1`, not `val`.

Moreover, you only assign values until `val-1`:

```
for(int m=0;m<val;m++)
//          ^ runs only while m<val, e.g. until (inclusive) m==val-1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cout<<t1[val];
```

is trying to access element `val+1` (array index ranges from `0` to `val-1`)

If you need to output all vals run a for loop over it.

```
for (int i=0; i< val; i++)
  cout<<t1[i];
```

Comment: No, `t1[val]` accesses element `val`, not `val + 1`.